# How to store the selected image in library to NSString

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to get the complete url of selected image from photo library in iphone to NSString.

Is it possible

My code is

```
    NSString *  filePath;
    UIImagePickerController * picker;
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;     
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    filePath = /* Here i ant to get the complete url of selected image*/
```

Please help

Comment: UIKit doesn't offer this information. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: here i want to send images from camera or photo library to ftp server

Answer (score 1):

So you want to send an image from UIImagePickerController to a ftp server. In your delegate method, take the in `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`, which is a `UIImage` object, and call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` to create a JPEG file. Then you can send the JPEG file to your ftp server.

Comment: i converted image into jpg but its not sending now...
I can send image from resource folder to ftp server

My code 

 filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xx"] ofType:@"jpg"];

Here i am sending xx.jpg from resourse folder to server and working fine.

How i can send library file

Comment: After converting to jpg how i will give url

Comment: The UIImageJPEGRepresentation gives you an NSData object from which you can pull the data directly and send to your FTP server. No need to write it to a file on the device.